# MVC Area routing - How to exclude area name in URL

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'd like to use "Areas" to separate the code and content of my CMS system and the content from the commerce part of the site.

So I'd like to create an area (called Commerce) that contains a Controller called "Buy". But Id like the routing to ignore the Commerce part of the route and instead create a URL that looks like "www.acme.com/Buy" instead of "www.acme.com/Commerce/Buy"

Is this possible?

Comment: This actually happens by default

Comment: @Kyle How this happens by default? Can you please describe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. But I am not sure than it's good approach.

After your area will be created, you have a new file [areaname]areaRegistration.cs
In RegisterArea method just remove area name from contex.MapRoute, somthing like this

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

as you can see I removed area name in this line

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

rather than

```
"[AreaName]/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```